# Why does DotNetNuke log me out on post ajax requests?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

Previously, when I tried to do an ajax call to an ashx as a non-superuser account (i.e. as portal specific user) my web server would return cookies to clear my authorization.  I [posted a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503890/why-is-dnn-killing-my-authentication-cookies-when-i-access-an-ashx-from-a-child) and it seemed the answer was to make sure that the `portalid=xx` was specified in my GET parameters.

However, I have just found out that if I add `portalid=xx` in a POST request, DotNetNuke seems to ignore and and log out any non-superuser account.

How can I keep authorization during DNN POST ajax requests?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a good handle on the whole situation, and unfortunately it appears that the only true solution is to make sure each child portal has its own subdomain rather than a sub-url (e.g. `portal.domain.com` rather than `domain.com/portal`).

The problem is that when your portal 0 is `domain.com` but portal 1 is `domain.com/portal` everything works correctly until you need to access an `.ashx` file via ajax.  What happens then is the URL that's requested is instead `domain.com/DesktopModules/MyModule/Handler.ashx`, which does not contain the `/portal/` in it, thus causing DNN to think you are doing a request on portal 0 and logging you out.

While GET requests can overcome this with a `portal=1` parameter, this does not seem to work for POST requests.

Therefore, the best solution it seems is to have your portal on a distinct subdomain (`portal.domain.com`), and then you don't risk missing something like this.

Comment: This answer is likely in the correct neighbourhood of what the problem is.  Any log out is usually caused by an ambiguous portal reference in the Url, which causes the request to incorrectly identify the portal that the request belongs to.

It's also important to understand exactly when the log-out occurs.  Sometimes it's a get in the overall group of requests that go into a page view, but it looks like you get logged out on the POST-  when in fact you're already logged out, and it doesn't matter what request happens next, it's always going to result in a non-authenticated response.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a few things for you to check out and see if any of them solve your problem.

- Make sure you are using a ScriptManagerProxy.  This allows ascx pages to use AJAX while the parent page is also using AJAX.
- There have been many reports of people not being able to run AJAX with DNN if Page State Persistence is set to "Memory".  Those who experience this have been able to fix it by switching Page State Persistence to "Page".  The easiest way to do this is to run this query:

  update HostSettings
  set SettingValue='P'
  where SettingName='PageStatePersister'

After you run that, you'll need to recycle the application.  If you don't have access to the server, just add a space or carriage return to your web.config file (that will force the app to recycle).

- Lastly, you might see if you have this line in your web.config.  Sometimes removing it will help:

  <system.web>
  <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />
  </system.web>

Comment: Have you had a chance to check out these possible solutions?

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to give this a try until today.  Unfortunately, none of those work.  I probably should also state I'm not using ASP.NET Ajax but jquery to perform my posts.